# If this word is found, replace just that word in that line of the file

Tags: java, file, io

I have a file, in this file there are situations like:

```
--

text

12345

12345text

12 text

--
```

Whenever the word

> text

is met, I want this word to be removed (not the numbers)

```
while (lineOfText != null)
   {
       if (lineOfText.contains(TEXT_TO_REMOVE))
       {
           lineOfText = "";
       }
       outputFile.println(lineOfText);
       lineOfText = inputFile.readLine();
   }
```

This fragment above removes the entire line, as you can see, any way to remove just the word

> text

and maintain the other numbers in the file?

*SOLVED*

Comment: try this, i hope lineOfText is String lineOfText.replaceAll(TEXT_TO_REMOVE,"")  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

Comment: `lineOfText = lineOfText.replaceAll("text", "");`

Comment: @ChosenForWorlds **lineOfText = ** lineOfText.replaceAll() you forgot to assign the result...

Comment: Yes that works. Sorry I didn't add this to the question, but if the word text is met, how would i delete all characters after the word text and the word text itself?

Comment: @ChosenForWorlds `.replaceAll("text.*", "");`...

Comment: @brso05 Thank you so much! Works! Wondering if I could use a constant instead of the string "text.*" so like .replaceAll(TEXT_TO_REMOVE, "")? with final String TEXT_TO_REMOVE = "text.*"? Tried this out, didn't work?

Comment: @ChosenForWorldsThere are many ways to improve the solution, please go through documentation https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html,

Comment: @ChosenForWorlds you're welcome! Glad I could help! `.replaceAll((TEXT_TO_REMOVE + ".*"), "");`

Comment: @ChosenForWorlds you're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

something like this..

```
TEXT_TO_REMOVE = TEXT_TO_REMOVE+".*";
      while (lineOfText != null)
           {
              lineOfText=     lineOfText.replaceAll(TEXT_TO_REMOVE, "");
               outputFile.println(lineOfText);
               lineOfText = inputFile.readLine();
           }
```